# functions like gethostbyname() and getlogin_r() stopping runtime execution on remote debugging

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I'm currently working with [Visual Studio Remote Development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/deploy-run-and-debug-your-linux-project?view=msvc-160), developing an application which is supposed to run on Linux but is developed on Windows. As remote machine, I'm using the WSL2 Ubuntu machine which runs on the same system as the VS dev env is running on.

I have following code snippet which stops everytime I'm running or debugging it. This code is quite C-like, however I'm compiling it using g++ since it's part of a bigger C++ project:

```cpp
struct passwd* pw { getpwuid(geteuid()) }; // execution stops here, program crashes

// [...] if I remove the above part, execution continues:

struct hostent* host { nullptr };
char hostname[64];
strncpy(hostname, "unknown", 64);
hostname[63]='\0';

gethostname(hostname, 64);

host = gethostbyname(hostname); // execution stops here, program crashes
```

Linux console output:

```
5675-exec-next
Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
Stopped due to shared library event:
  Inferior loaded /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2
5676-break-info 2
5677-break-info 4
5678-break-info 5
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2'. Symbols loaded.
Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
Stopped due to shared library event:
  Inferior loaded /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/UTF-16.so
5680-break-info 2
5681-break-info 4
5682-break-info 5
Loaded '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/UTF-16.so'. Symbols loaded.
Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
Stopped due to shared library event:
  Inferior loaded /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.2
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2
5684-break-info 2
5685-break-info 4
5686-break-info 5
Loaded '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.2'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2'. Symbols loaded.
```

Problem here is that I don't see any simple error or abort message, no debugger output is provided in any way.

I have setup a simple test file inside WSL (which probably has some unnecessary includes, sorry for that) to test if the function basically works:

```cpp
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct hostent* hp = gethostbyname("MY-HOSTNAME\0");

    if (hp == nullptr) {
        printf("failed.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("%s = ", hp->h_name);
        int i = 0;

        while (hp->h_addr_list[i] != nullptr) {
            printf("%s", inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)(hp->h_addr_list[i])));
            ++i;
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output: `MY-HOSTNAME = 127.0.0.1`

So basically the function seems to be working inside the subsystem.

The same problem appears when using `getlogin_r(hostname)` or `getpwuid(geteuid())`.

Is it possible that maybe VS remote debugger loads false libraries when initializing the debugger (which I have set to be `gdb`)?

Comment: the result of `gethostname` may not be null terminated

Comment: @AlanBirtles you mean if it's longer than 64 chars?